# How to get ATR of a smard card from HID omnilkey

Tags: python-2.7, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard, pyscard

I want to get ATR of the smartcard. I am using HID omnikey 5321. I am following this link "http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/user-guide.html#requesting-any-card"

so far i have tried:

```
>>>from smartcard.CardType import AnyCardType
>>>from smartcard.CardRequest import CardRequest
>>>from smartcard.util import toHexString
>>>
>>> cardtype = AnyCardType()
>>> cardrequest = CardRequest( timeout=1, cardType=cardtype )
>>> cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard() 
>>>
>>>>>> cardservice.connection.connect()
```

i am getting error at the

```
cardservice.connection.connect()
```

error like:

```
raise CardConnectionException('Unable to connect with ptotocol[pcscprotocol] + . '+ScardGetErrorMessage(hresult) 
CardConnectionException: Unable to conenct the card with T0 or T1 . Card is not responding to reset.
```

Comment: Is your card contactless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because You dont specify the reader to connect:

```
r=readers()
#r[Number of reader list].
cardservice.connection = r[0].createConnection()
cardservice.connection.connect()
```

- 

A simple Example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from smartcard.Exceptions import NoCardException
from smartcard.System import readers
from smartcard.util import toHexString

for reader in readers():
    try:
         connection = reader.createConnection()
         connection.connect()
         print(reader, toHexString(connection.getATR()))
    except NoCardException:
         print(reader, 'no card inserted')

import sys
if 'win32' == sys.platform:
    print('press Enter to continue')
    sys.stdin.read(1)
```

-Another Selecting Reader:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from smartcard.Exceptions import NoCardException
from smartcard.System import readers
from smartcard.util import toHexString
from smartcard.CardType import AnyCardType
from smartcard.CardRequest import CardRequest

cardtype = AnyCardType()
r=readers()
cardrequest = CardRequest( timeout=10, cardType=cardtype )
cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()
print('Available Readers:')
for i in range(len(readers())):
    print('[',i+1,']',r[i])
if(len(readers()) < 1):
    print("\nNO AVAILABLE READERS!\n")
else:
    print("Select you Reader: (Ctrl+C to Exit)")
    my_input = input()
    selectReader = clamp(int(my_input)-1,0,len(readers()))
    print('Selected: ',r[selectReader])
    cardservice.connection = r[selectReader].createConnection()
    cardservice.connection.connect()
    try:
        print('Card ATR:',toHexString(cardservice.connection.getATR()),file=f)
    except:
        print("Cant not Get ATR")
```

.

Full Information:

https://pyscard.sourceforge.io/pyscard-framework.html#framework-samples

https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pyscard

https://pyscard.sourceforge.io/user-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can use the pyscard library to interact with smart cards, there is an example that should help you display the ATR at http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/pyscard-framework.html#framework-samples

Comment: In the above link there is javascript mentioned in it. how can get with that

Comment: i want to get it from python not from webpage, and does all the cards have ATR?? why because i have got nothing when i am accessing the atr of the card i am gettign a empty list